# Is it possible - to template this method?

Tags: java, swing, templates, generics

I am new in Java and i have a few questions for more advanced developers.

I have Swing-based GUI application in which I have several `AbstractActions`.
A large group of `AbstractActions` creates new tab based on `JPanel`. For example:

```
// opens "Documents" tab
documentsAction = new AbstractAction(DOCUMENTS) {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
      int index = getTabIndex(DOCUMENTS);
      if (index >= 0) {
        // Tab exists, just open it.
        tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(index);
      } else {
        // No tab. Create it and open
        newCatalogTab(new DocumentService(), DOCUMENTS);
      }
    } catch (ServiceException ex) {
      printError(ex.getMessage());
    }
  }
};
documentsItem.setAction(documentsAction);
```

Where `getTabIndex` is:

```
  private int getTabIndex(String tabName) {
    int result = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < tabbedPane.getTabCount(); i++) {
      if (tabName.equals(tabbedPane.getTitleAt(i))) {
        result = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

and `newCatalogTab` is:

```
  private void newCatalogTab(ICatalog service, String Name) throws ServiceException {
    CatalogPanel panel = new CatalogPanel(service);
    tabbedPane.add(Name, panel);
    tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(tabbedPane.getTabCount() - 1);
    checkTabs(); // changes activity of buttons like "edit" and "delete"
  }
```

So, many `AbstractAction` do the similar work:

1. Create instance of class, that extends `AbstractPanel`;
2. Pass data access interface (`DocumentService` in example) to instance;
3. Create a new tab with instance.

Can I somehow template this if data access interfaces will use different POJO's?
Can I create Generic interface and use it?
Can you show me right direction for thinking?

Thanks for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no templates in Java, so there will be some code duplication in any case. However, you can cut some of the boilerplate code by using [factories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). For example:

```
interface CatalogFactory {
    public ICatalog makeCatalog();
}

class DocumentServiceFactory implements CatalogFactory {
    @Override
    public ICatalog makeCatalog() {
        return new DocumentService();
    }
}

class TabAction extends AbstractAction {
    private final String name;
    private final CatalogFactory factory;

    //Appropriate constructor...

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //...
        newCatalogTab(factory.makeCatalog(), name);
        //...
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
documentsItem.setAction(new TabAction(DOCUMENTS, new DocumentServiceFactory()));
```

without having to create a separate anonymous AbstractAction for each tab.

Similarly for panels and possibly other objects where this pattern fits.